# Displaying multiple independent windows with images in tkinter, and having the main loop exit when they have all been closed

Tags: python, tkinter

My plotting library needs to be able to show multiple plots at the same time, each of which is represented as a PIL image, and each of which should show up as its own window. The windows should be independent, so closing any one of them should not affect the others, but when all of them have been closed the main loop should exit. This behavior was easy to achieve in qt and wx, but in qt it's proving difficult so far.

Here's the closest I've come so far:

```
from six.moves import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk

class Window:
  def __init__(self, img):
    self.window = tkinter.Toplevel()
    self.window.minsize(img.width, img.height)
    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width=img.width, height=img.height)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.configure(background="white")
    self.photo  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    self.sprite = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
windows = []
for img in imgs:
  windows.append(Window(img))
if len(windows) > 0: windows[0].window.mainloop()
```

This displays an image in each window, and each of those windows can be closed independently. But it also displays an empty root window which needs to be closed for the main loop to exit, and which will cause all windows to close when closed, which is not the behavior I want.

If I replace `tkinter.Toplevel()` with `tkinter.Tk()`, then create_image fails for the second window with an obscure "pyimageX does not exist" error message, where X is an incrementing integer.

Will I have to make an invisible root window, and then manually count how many child windows have closed and trigger destruction of the invisible root window when all of them have closed in order to get the behavior I'm looking for? Or is there a simple way to achieve this?

Edit: Just to clarify: My program is not mainly a Tk app. It spends almost all its time doing other stuff, and only temporarily uses Tk in a single function to display some plots. That's why it's important that the main loop exits after the plots have been closed, to the program can resume its normal operation. Think about how `show()` in matplotlib works for an example of this scenario.

Comment: Toplevel is the only way you should be creating multiple windows. There should be exactly one root window and them toplevels after that.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have tried making the first window Tk() and all the following ones Toplevel(). That gives the right number of windows, but closing the toplevel window leads to all of them being closed, which isn't what I want. I only want the main loop to exit once all the windows have been closed.

Comment: I am assuming you mean that closing the Tk window makes the program exit, however you could put all the images in toplevels and suppress the main window

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Yes, I've tried that too, but then the main loop hangs forever when all the windows are closed. I need the normal control flow of the program to resume after the tk stuff is done. Avoiding this hang is what I'm talking about in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: @amaurea Ah yes. No time now but when I come back I'll look at a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might want to do this. This example uses the root window to house a button that will open up all images at the top level.

Make sure you change `self.path` to your image folder.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(self, text="Open Images", command=self.open_images).pack()
        self.path = ".\RGB"
    def open_images(self):
        directory = os.fsencode(self.path)

        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(".gif"): 
                print(filename)
                top = tk.Toplevel(self)
                img = tk.PhotoImage(file="{}\{}".format(self.path, filename))
                lbl = tk.Label(top, image=img)
                lbl.image = img
                lbl.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Here is my 2nd example where you can hide the root window and when the last top level window is closed the tkinter instance is also destroyed. This is maned with a simple tracking variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.top_level_count = 0
        self.path = ".\RGB"
        self.open_images()
        self.withdraw()

    def open_images(self):
        directory = os.fsencode(self.path)
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(".gif"): 
                self.top_level_count += 1
                image_top(self, self.path, filename)


    def check_top_count(self):
        print(self.top_level_count)
        if self.top_level_count <= 0:
            self.destroy()


class image_top(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, controller, path, filename):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, controller)  
        self.controller = controller 
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.handle_close)             
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="{}\{}".format(path, filename))
        lbl = tk.Label(self, image=img)
        lbl.image = img
        lbl.pack()

    def handle_close(self):
        self.controller.top_level_count -= 1
        self.destroy()
        self.controller.check_top_count()


if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this solution has a root window that stays alive even after the last image window has been closed. This is the situation I'm trying to avoid. I'll edit my question to make this more clear, but my program is not a standard graphical tk program. Instead, it spends most of its time having nothing to do with tk, and only does tk stuff inside a single function to display some plots. After the function exits tk should get out of the way again. That's why need the main loop to stop after the plot windows are closed. matplotlib's show() command is an example of this.

Comment: @amaurea you can keep track and have it close when the last window closes

Comment: OK. That's what I feared. I'm working on that now, using protocol and WM_DELETE_WINDOW, hoping that this will catch all causes of the window closing.

Comment: @amaurea I have added a 2nd example that should do exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: That's very similar to what I ended up with. I had hoped something simpler would be possible, but this works. Accepting.

Comment: @amaurea when dealing with tkinter there is not a simple way that I am aware of to monitor how many top level windows are open. There might be a way to check how many are currently active and if no top level windows active then close program. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's a couple of classes I came up with to solve this problem:

```
class ImgRoot(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, imgs):
        super(ImgRoot, self).__init__()
        for i in imgs:
            Window(self, i)
        self.withdraw()
        self.open=True
        self.tick()
    def tick(self):
        if not self.open:
            self.destroy()
        self.open=False
        self.after(100, self.tick)
    def checkin(self):
        self.open=True
class Window(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, img):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.root=root
        self.tick()
        self.minsize(img.width, img.height)
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, width=img.width, height=img.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.configure(background="white")
        self.photo  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.sprite = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
    def tick(self):
        self.root.checkin()
        self.after(100, self.tick)
```

The idea here is to create a main class (`ImgRoot`) which handles the whole thing. Then, every 0.1 seconds (100 miliseconds), it will check if any of the image windows have told it that they are still alive, and, if not, close. The image windows (`Window`s) do this by setting the `ImgRoot`'s `open` attribute to `True` every 0.1 seconds that they are alive. Here is an example usage:

```
import tkinter
#above classes go here
ImgRoot(imgs) #imgs is a list as defined in your question
tkinter.mainloop()
print('done') #or whatever you want to do next
```

Comment: I know you've got a working answer, but here's another. Tell me if you have any problems/questions, I've not tested it with actual images yet.